# How can I pass input stream to Utf8JsonReader in C#?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, stream, jsonreader

So I am trying to read in a serialized JSON file. So a part of my code currently looks like this

```
using (Stream input = File.OpenRead(openDialog.FileName))
using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(input))
```

This is part of a larger project. Per another StackOverflow post I have created my own Converter to deserialize my objects of the correct type, and I am realizing the read method for the custom type converter class uses Utf8JsonReader to read in the JSON.
So my question is this, how can I achieve something like:

```
using Utf8JsonReader reader = new Utf8JsonReader(input))
```

So that I can pass in the input stream from the file system? I have looked at the the other SO post that is supposed to answer this, but it made me more confused. So that I can achieve this:

```
using (Stream input = File.OpenRead(openDialog.FileName))
//reader solution here 
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
      Converters = { new BaseClassConverter() },

};
MyObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<BaseClass>(reader.GetString(), options);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: There's litterally no point in using a stream if you read all of its content in one go.

Comment: @aybe But I am reading a file in from the open file dialog currently with BinaryReader. What the workaround for this be then?

Comment: `File.ReadAllText` ???